# How to install gnu ld on mac os x 10.6?

Tags: macos, ld, binutils

I'm having a lot of trouble compiling the otherwise excellent [Contiki OS](http://www.sics.se/contiki/) on my macbook pro (with mac os x 10.6). Contiki actually uses a lot of GNU-specific features and options of GCC, AR, LD, and so on. So I installed those utilities via macports, but it looks like "port install binutils" does not install GNU ld, does it ?

So, the question is, how do I get GNU ld on my mac ? Is there a simple alternative to the hard-way (i.e. the `wget, configure, make, make install` way) ?

Comment: The "hard" way isn't that hard... (unless something goes wrong of course)

Comment: Sure ; but in this case I very much doubt that I will get better results than what macport gets (because macports *does* the " wget && configure && make" thing)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290431/ld-linking-error-while-compiling-z3

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260504/macports-installing-binutils

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I can tell, GNU binutils does not support the [Mach-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) format. None of the [documentation](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/) mentions it, and some Googling turns up some [recent messages](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2009-09/msg00121.html) indicating that it is not supported.

Now, you mention the Contiki OS, which looks to me like an embedded operating system. Are you needing to compile to a native executable, or are you trying to cross-compile for some other environment? MacPorts does include [several ports of binutils](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=binutils) for cross compilation.

Comment: indeed ; my long term goal is to do cross-compilation, of course. But at first I wanted to try the "native platform" target, in order to get familiar with the programming model and all that. However it looks more and more like "native" means "GNU/linux" and only "GNU/linux" :-(

Comment: It looks like you're right; they appear to need a GNU toolchain, which generally means Linux or Cygwin. You can always install Linux to a virtual machine. I've had good luck installing Ubuntu server edition (as it's lighter weight than the desktop edition, not including the all the desktop software) onto a VirtualBox VM http://www.virtualbox.org/ for a quick and easy free Linux VM.

Comment: Yep, thanks for your help. I'm now starting to play with debian in a virtualbox. after all, it will probably be cool to have a linux environment at hand as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ port info binutils
(…) Tools are prefixed with g to avoid conflicts with original tools. (…)
```

Comment: Sure, but :

% ls /opt/local/var/macports/software/binutils/2.19_0/opt/local/bin
gaddr2line gnm   granlib  gstrings
gar  gobjcopy greadelf gstrip
gc++filt gobjdump gsize

Comment: % ls /opt/local/bin/gld
ls: /opt/local/bin/gld: No such file or directory

Comment: long story short, everything is there *but* ld, hence my question.

Comment: Aha, you’re right. I’ve just installed binutils and have no gld either. Sorry for the false trace.

Comment: No worries :-)  but do you know what's wrong with them ? Why on earth won't binutils install "ld" ??