# file not found: –Ttext

Tags: assembly

I can't compile this piece of assembler code under Mac OS using this:

```
.text
    .global _start
_start:
    . = _start + 510
    .byte 0x55
    .byte 0xaa
```

```
ld –Ttext 0x7c00 --oformat=binary test.o –o test.bin
```

instruction in a result terminal:

```
ld: file not found: –Ttext
```

Could you tell me why this doesn't work, but also if there is an alternative to this instruction to compile in the desired format.
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Are you using gnu ld or the one that comes with OSX?

Comment: I'm not sure, but on my machine I installed GNU and by default there was already Clang so I would bet on the GNU one, but apparently it doesn't work on Mac.

`gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin`

Comment: What does `ld -v` show? If I were you I'd compile it in a linux VM. It will save you a lot of time and grief.

Comment: This gives me the following result:
`ld -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-278.4
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em (tvOS)
LTO support using: LLVM version 8.1.0, (clang-802.0.42)
TAPI support using: Apple TAPI version 1.33.11`

honestly I would still be dependent on VM I prefer to do it under Mac... but I would consider this option if there is no other choice.

Comment: OK I will test and I will give you the result if I encounter difficulties thank you

Comment: Maybe this is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634708/gnu-linker-equivalent-command-in-os-x

Comment: Did you install gcc with homebrew? If so you should be able to use `/usr/local/i386elfgcc/bin/i386-elf-ld` with your original commandline args.

Comment: Thanks to you I was able to find an alternative solution thanks to your link 
`gobjcopy -j .text --set-start 0x7c00 -O binary source.o boot.bin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this relevant question [GNU Linker equivalent command in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634708/gnu-linker-equivalent-command-in-os-x)

and the OP did the heavy lifting to find the solution:

```
gobjcopy -j .text --set-start 0x7c00 -O binary source.o boot.bin
```

--

UPDATE: See comments below.

TLDR: Do not use the above. Instead, build (or acquire) a generic ELF binutils which will give you access to a version of LD that is based on GNU's tool chain. That version of LD supports proper linker scripts and is far more easy to do OS development with.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. You will have serious problems since you are converting an unlinked `.o` (object) file to a binary. As the person points out that it causes problems for label offsets. the real solution is to acquire or build an i686 (or x86-64) binutils and GCC cross compiler

Comment: @MichaelPetch OK I will delete this answer. But before I do, why would it require a cross compiler?

Comment: If you build (or acquire) a generic ELF binutils it will give you access to a version of _LD_ that is based on GNU's tool chain. That version of _LD_ supports proper linker scripts and is far more easy to do OS development with. The _LD_ available on OS/X is limited in comparison.

Comment: All right, I'm trying to understand. Outside the link provided with the provided solution which according to your statements is not correct. 
A simple `nasm -f bin bootloader.asm -o boot.bin followed by a simple 'cat boot.bin /dev/zero | dd of=floppyA bs=512 count=2880
` still allows you to get an  **boot loader**
The previous step was another approach to design **boot loader** so what do you propose as an alternative or suitable tool for building an operating system under Mac OS ?
thanks

Answer (score 3):

The first character in `–Ttext` is `–` U+2013 (EN DASH).

You need to use `-` U+002D (HYPHEN-MINUS) instead.

Comment: Good catch ! Another victim of copy-pasting from auto-"corrected" MsWord documents?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your answer. Could you explain me more, because I'm trying to compile my boot sector.

Comment: Don't use `–Ttext`; use `-Ttext` instead.