# How to fix "error: no member named 'fancy_abort' in namespace 'std::__1'; did you mean simply 'fancy_abort'? _VSTD::abort();"

Tags: macos, gcc

Platform: Macos Catalina 10.15.2 
Xcode version: Xcode 11

I have tried many times to `make-all gcc` to build my source code. However, I have encountered a problem:

```
In file included from ../.././gcc/c/c-objc-common.c:33: 
In file included from /Applications/Xcode11.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/new:85: 
/Applications/Xcode11.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/exception:181:5: error:
      no member named 'fancy_abort' in namespace 'std::__1'; did you mean simply 'fancy_abort'?
    _VSTD::abort();
    ^~~~~~~ /Applications/Xcode11.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__config:873:15: note:
      expanded from macro '_VSTD'  # _VSTD std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE
              ^ ../.././gcc/system.h:685:13: note: 'fancy_abort' declared here extern void fancy_abort (const char *, int, const char
*) ATTRIBUTE_NORETURN;
            ^ 
1 error generated. 
make[1]: *** [c/c-objc-common.o] Error 1  
make: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
```

I have tried to install another version of Xcode. I have installed Xcode6 but it still did not work, and I found a [solution of this issue](https://github.com/osx-cross/homebrew-avr/issues/51#issuecomment-364172149). But when I download Xcode8.3.3, it is not compatible with Catalina 10.15.2.

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to this issue while using crosstools-ng on mac (mojave 10.14) to compile cross-platform toolchain with gcc 4.9.

Solution: Edit .build/src/gcc-4.9.4/gcc/system.h to add `#include <map>` in `#ifdef __cplusplus` block where other include statements are.

> The problem is that  is included (via ) after abort has been
> defined as a macro to fancy_abort. And thus when the C++ standard headers try
> to call std::abort, they end up calling std::fancy_abort, which of course
> doesn't exist.

Source: https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-bugs/2017-09/msg00154.html